# Best way to load images for OpenGL in NaCl

Tags: google-chrome, opengl, png, jpeg, google-nativeclient

What is the best way to load the actual image data from .png or .jpg files for use in OpenGL within Chromes NaCl??

Is there a PPAPI feature that can do this?  I didn't think there was.

I was thinking about using javaScript to load the Image data and pass it back to NaCl.  Is this possible?  If so what javaScript method do you use to pass the Image data to NaCl, cuz I don't think postMessage is what I want for that?

Frustrating how there must be an image loading backend to Chrome but no way to access it via NaCl.

Comment: NOTE: I also made my own format that takes up about as much as a .png file.  Just compress raw rgba data as a zip and load it back is the easiest way to handle losless images for textures that dont take up much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 3 ways of doing it.

1. You can use nacl-mounts library to load files from server and store it locally to use it within your app.
2. You can also see [GetUrl example in nacl sdk](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git/+/master/native_client_sdk/src/examples/api/url_loader/url_loader.cc) to load files from server and directly use it.
3. There is also a new example in pepper_21 which loads texture and set it to a cube.

Comment: This new pepper_21 demo... Does it require non-stop async loading?  Or can you stop the main thread to load image data... This is rly the biggest issue with NaCl for me right now as its not able to stop the main thread to load data file.  Makes cross platform apps a pain in the but to make.  I have figured out a async method by buffing all needed file objects in a list and then using normal streams to read the memory from there(so it fakes real system IO).  Although this is really just a hack for the missing features in NaCl.

Comment: Actually there is no Direct way to stop main thread in any case. As the files have to e loaded from server, you actually can't stop main thread, which will make the browser to hang for a while. But you can fake it easily using a thread and a isImagesLoaded Boolean.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the file in Javascript you can also create a blob url and then load that from NaCL using GetUrl as described.

Comment: ya, when I start doing more in NaCl again, I will probably use javaScript to load .png, .jpg files ects...  Write now I made my own image format called .bmpc, basically a compressed .bmp file with an alpha channel to replace .png.  Its accually almost the same size as .png in most cases.  I also use my own loader for .dds/dxt files.